# in Visual studio 2010 MASM file doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86

If I run the ASM files in Visual Studio 2010 project, it is crashing  after asm functions are called

using asm code:-

```
.386           
.model flat, c 
TEXT        SEGMENT
ALIGN       4  
L_add PROC

   push     ebp                   
   mov      ebp, esp

   mov      edx, dword ptr[ebp + 12]
   mov      eax, dword ptr[ebp + 8]
   add      edx, eax

   mov      esp, ebp  
   pop      ebp                                      
   ret      0                
   L_add ENDP
   TEXT     ENDS
   END**
```

The above code is not working in visual studio 2010, if I change `TEXT  SEGMENT` as `.code` segment it is working fine, what is difference between `.code` and  `TEXT SEGMENT` but above code has work on visual studio 2005.

```
disaasembly at calling place:
b = hs_L_shl(L_var1,var2);
012D1484  movsx       eax,word ptr [var2]  
012D1488  push        eax  
012D1489  mov         ecx,dword ptr [L_var1]  
012D148C  push        ecx  
012D148D  call        @ILT+455(_hs_L_shl) (12D11CCh)  
012D1492  add         esp,8  
012D1495  mov         dword ptr [b],eax

Disaasembly at function with .code: 
hs_L_shl PROC


  ;  PROLOGUE START

   push  ebp                    
012D15B0  push        ebp  
   mov  ebp, esp
012D15B1  mov         ebp,esp  
   sub      esp, 24               
012D15B3  sub         esp,18h  
   push  ebx
012D15B6  push        ebx  
   push     esi
012D15B7  push        esi

Disaasembly at function with TEXT SEGMENT: 

  ;  PROLOGUE START

   push  ebp                   
012D15B0  push        ebp  
   mov  ebp, esp
012D15B1  mov         ebp,esp  
   sub      esp, 24                
012D15B3  sub         esp,18h  
   push  ebx
012D15B6  push        ebx  
   push     esi
012D15B7  push        esi
```

Comment: How about looking at the disassembly of this code? That should give you some ideas about what's wrong and what the difference is.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze this code (shown above) *is already* in asm. By "disassembly" one understands the process of converting a byte code into asm. This is not applicable to this code since it's already asm. Perhaps you mean disassembling of the resulting binary?

Comment: @zespri Exactly, the disassembly of the resulting binary, in two places: this function and the function(s) where it's called from. It's possible that there may be different calling conventions or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  That it doesn't compile?  Or that it doesn't run as expected?

Comment: @selbie I think he explained it in the question, you probably missed this part: "it is crashing after asm functions are called". So basically when the app runs after entering the asm code above the app crashes. That's how I understand it.

Comment: @zespri - Agreed. He should step through with a debugger to see where it's crashing.It would be great if he posted the code that shows how he's calling this function.

Comment: it is compiling with asm files but it is crashing after entring asm function with TEXT SEGMENT, but it is not crashing if i keep .code instead of TEXT SEGMENT. what is the difference between them

Comment: What if you change the name of your segment from `TEXT` to `_TEXT`?  That's the default name used by `.code` (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx6f0y31%28v=vs.100%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx6f0y31%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

it crashes because the return address is not where it should be.   the function takes 2 parameters pushed onto the stack right?  Then why are you using `ret 0`, you should be using `ret 8`

Comment: Not if he's using the cdecl calling convention, which the code indicates (note the `.model flat, c` and the `add esp,8` instruction after `call`).